# Correcting regex patterns across languages

Tags: c#, .net, regex

I found this regex pattern at http://gskinner.com/RegExr/

```
,(?=(?:[^"]*"[^"]*")*(?![^"]*"))
```

Which is for pattern matching CSV delimited values (more specifically, the separating commas, which can be split on), which on that site works excellently with my test data. You can see what I think is the JavaScript implementation in the bottom panel of the site linked when tested.

However when I attempt to implement this in C# / .net, the matching doesn't quite work properly.
My implementation:

```
Regex r = new Regex(",(?=(?:[^\"]*\"[^\"]*\")*(?![^\"]*\"))", RegexOptions.ECMAScript);
//get data...
foreach (string match in r.Split(sr.ReadLine()))
{
    //lblDev.Text = lblDev.Text + match + "<br><br><br><p>column:</p><br>";
    dtF.Columns.Add(match);
}

//more of the same to get rows
```

On some data rows the result exactly matches the result generated on the site above, but on others the first 6 or so rows fail to split or simply are not present in the split array.

Can anyone advise me on why the pattern does not appear to be behaving in the same way?

my test data:

```
CategoryName,SubCategoryName,SupplierName,SupplierCode,ProductTitle,Product Company ,ProductCode,Product_Index,ProductDescription,Product BestSeller,ProductDimensions,ProductExpressDays,ProductBrandName,ProductAdditionalText ,ProductPrintArea,ProductPictureRef,ProductThumnailRef,ProductQuantityBreak1 (QB1),ProductQuantityBreak2 (QB2),ProductQuantityBreak3 (QB3),ProductQuantityBreak4 (QB4),ProductPlainPrice1,ProductPlainPrice2,ProductPlainPrice3,ProductPlainPrice4,ProductColourPrice1,ProductColourPrice2,ProductColourPrice3,ProductColourPrice4,ProductExtraColour1,ProductExtraColour2,ProductExtraColour3,ProductExtraColour4,SellingPrice1,SellingPrice2,SellingPrice3,SellingPrice4,ProductCarriageCost1,ProductCarriageCost2,ProductCarriageCost3,ProductCarriageCost4,BLACK,BLUE,WHITE,SILVER,GOLD,RED,YELLOW,GREEN,ProductOtherColors,ProductOrigination,ProductOrganizationCost,ProductCatalogEntry,ProductPageNumber,ProductPersonalisationType1 (PM1),ProductPrintPosition,ProductCartonQuantity,ProductCartonWeight,ProductPricingExpering,NewProduct,ProductSpecialOffer,ProductSpecialOfferEnd,ProductIsActive,ProductRepeatOrigination,ProductCartonDimession,ProductSpecialOffer1,ProductIsExpress,ProductIsEco,ProductIsBiodegradable,ProductIsRecycled,ProductIsSustainable,ProductIsNatural
Audio,Speakers and Headphones,The Prime Time Company,CM5064:In-ear headphones,Silly Buds,,10058,372,"Small, trendy ear buds with excellent sound quality and printing area actually on each ear- piece. Plastic storage box, with room for cables be wrapped around can also be printed.",FALSE,70 x 70 x 20mm,,,,10mm dia,10058.jpg,10058.jpg,100,250,500,1000,2.19,2.13,2.06,1.99,0.1,0.1,0.05,0.05,0.1,0.1,0.05,0.05,3.81,3.71,3.42,3.17,0,0,0,0,FALSE,FALSE,FALSE,FALSE,FALSE,FALSE,FALSE,FALSE,,30,,TRUE,24,Screen Printed,Earpiece,200,11,,TRUE,,,TRUE,15,,,FALSE,FALSE,FALSE,FALSE,FALSE,FALSE
Audio,Speakers and Headphones,The Prime Time Company,CM5058:Headstart,Head Start,,10060,372,"Lightweight, slimline, foldable and patented headphones ideal for the gym or exercise. These
headphones uniquely hang from the ears giving security, comfort and an excellent sound quality. There is also a secret cable winding facility.",FALSE,130 x 85 x 45mm,,,,30mm dia,10060.jpg,10060.jpg,100,250,500,1000,5.6,5.43,5.26,5.09,0.1,0.1,0.05,0.05,0.1,0.1,0.05,0.05,9.47,8.96,8.24,7.97,0,0,0,0,FALSE,FALSE,FALSE,FALSE,FALSE,FALSE,FALSE,FALSE,,30,,TRUE,24,Screen Printed,print plate on ear (s),100,11,,TRUE,,,TRUE,15,,,FALSE,FALSE,FALSE,FALSE,FALSE,FALSE
```

Comment: Do you mean the first six rows or the first six columns? If rows; then you need to look at the `sr.ReadLine()` and the loop surrounding that to make sure you are reading the data correctly. Also; I note that your test data includes a newline in the middle of the Product Description column in the second data row. Newlines like that will affect your results.

Answer (score 3):

Use the right tool for the job.  Regex is not well suited for parsing CSV which can have unlimited numbers of nested quotes.

Use this instead:

**A Fast CSV Reader**

http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/9258/A-Fast-CSV-Reader

We use it in production code.  It works great and makes you appreciate how complex parsing can be. For even more information on the complexity, check out the over 800 unit tests included in the solution.

Answer (score 0):

Your C# regex works fine for me in LinqPad, but your data does include a newline within the last "row" of data. So you can't simply use `sr.ReadLine()` to read the data.